# Can an opponent make me discard a Miracle card before I cast it, after it is revealed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, if my hand is empty and I draw and reveal [Temporal Mastery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Temporal%20Mastery), can an opponent cast [Funeral Charm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Funeral%20Charm) and make me discard it before I have a chance to cast it for its Miracle Cost?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Miracle triggers upon revealing the card when you draw it. You cannot cast the card until the triggered ability resolves and you pay the cost. Until that time, the card is in your hand and subject to the effects of discard.

> 702.93. Miracle
>
> 702.93a Miracle is a static ability linked to a triggered ability (see rule 603.10). "Miracle [cost]" means "You may reveal this card from your hand as you draw it if it's the first card you've drawn this turn. When you reveal this card this way, you may cast it by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost."
>
> 702.93b If a player chooses to reveal a card using its miracle ability, he or she plays with that card revealed until that card leaves his or her hand, that ability resolves, or that ability otherwise leaves the stack.

Comment: Won a game once by using Surgical Extraction on Bonfire of the Damned in response to my opponent revealing a second Bonfire. Good times.

Answer (score 8):

**It depends on whether the Miracle card is a Sorcery or Instant**

It would be correct to say: Your opponent can make you discard a Miracle card before you can cast it *for its Miracle cost*, as user1873 already pointed out.

If the card is a sorcery, you can't usually play it outside the main phase or with a non-empty stack, so for your specific example, he could make you discard before you can cast it in any way.

If it's an Instant, however, you can still play it for its regular cost in response to the Funeral Charm.

Comment: Indeed, I was wondering about paying the Miracle Cost. I have clarified the question to reflect that.

Comment: If you are casting it as a Miracle the Avacyn restored FAQ says specifically that you ignore timing restrictions.  I am not sure the Sorcery vs Instant applies to this question.  [Restored FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/faq/avr)

Comment: @Akedren We already established that the Charm is faster than the Miracle alternative cost. The original question asked whether the card can be played at all, and if the Miracle card is an Instant, it can be played for its *regular* cost rather than its Miracle cost, in response to the Charm. You can **choose** between Miracle and regular cost, you are not forced to play it for its Miracle cost if you reveal the card.